# How to format a JSON string as a table using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I need to convert a JSON string using jq, as shown below, into a table format for displaying the output in the terminal.

```
{
  "results": [
    [
      {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "value": "2023-07-03 08:28:00.000"
      },
      {
        "field": "CpuReserved",
        "value": "8192.0"
      },
      {
        "field": "CpuUtilized",
        "value": "4056.412942708333"
      },
      {
        "field": "MemoryReserved",
        "value": "61440"
      },
      {
        "field": "MemoryUtilized",
        "value": "4311"
      },
      {
        "field": "@ptr",
        "value": "CpABClUKUTE0NjcxNzAzNzI0NzovYXdzL2Vjcy9jb250YWluZXJpbnNpZ2h0cy9pcmwtaW5mcmEtc2hhcmVkLWplbmtpbnMtbWFpbi9wZXJmb3JtYW5jZRABEjUaGAIGSaxosQAAAAAd+TFeAAZKKHIwAAABEiABKIDF9taRMTDA7v3WkTE4BkC9NEjNPFCBIRgAEAAYAQ=="
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "value": "2023-07-03 08:28:00.000"
      },
      {
        "field": "CpuReserved",
        "value": "8192.0"
      },
      {
        "field": "CpuUtilized",
        "value": "4056.412942708333"
      },
      {
        "field": "MemoryReserved",
        "value": "61440"
      },
      {
        "field": "MemoryUtilized",
        "value": "4311"
      },
      {
        "field": "@ptr",
        "value": "CpABClUKUTE0NjcxNzAzNzI0NzovYXdzL2Vjcy9jb250YWluZXJpbnNpZ2h0cy9pcmwtaW5mcmEtc2hhcmVkLWplbmtpbnMtbWFpbi9wZXJmb3JtYW5jZRABEjUaGAIGSaxosQAAAAAd+TFeAAZKKHIwAAABEiABKIDF9taRMTDA7v3WkTE4BkC9NEjNPFCBIRgAEAEYAQ=="
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I want to display in the terminal is as follows:

```
@timestamp                CpuReserved  CpuUtilized         MemoryReserved   MemoryUtilized  
==========================================================================================
2023-07-03 08:16:00.000   8192.0       410.5300065104166   61440            1417
2023-07-03 08:15:00.000   8192.0       702.310791015625    61440            792
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$ jq -c '.results[]|map(.key=.field)|from_entries|del(."@ptr")' file.json |
   mlr --ijson --opprint --barred cat
+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| @timestamp              | CpuReserved | CpuUtilized       | MemoryReserved | MemoryUtilized |
+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2023-07-03 08:28:00.000 | 8192.0      | 4056.412942708333 | 61440          | 4311           |
| 2023-07-03 08:28:00.000 | 8192.0      | 4056.412942708333 | 61440          | 4311           |
+-------------------------+-------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Without `--barred`, that looks like:

```
@̲t̲i̲m̲e̲s̲t̲a̲m̲p̲              C̲p̲u̲R̲e̲s̲e̲r̲v̲e̲d̲ C̲p̲u̲U̲t̲i̲l̲i̲z̲e̲d̲       M̲e̲m̲o̲r̲y̲R̲e̲s̲e̲r̲v̲e̲d̲ M̲e̲m̲o̲r̲y̲U̲t̲i̲l̲i̲z̲e̲d̲
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000 8192.0      4056.412942708333 61440          4311
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000 8192.0      4056.412942708333 61440          4311
```

You could also pipe the output of that `jq` command to `vd -f json` ([VisiData](https://www.visidata.org/)) instead of `mlr` ([Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/)) to get an interactive table viewer.

Those use `jq` to extract the information and `mlr` only to format the table. There is some overlap between the feature set of `jq` and that of `mlr`. For instance, you could also remove the `@ptr` column with `mlr`'s `cut`:

```
jq -c '.results[]|map(.key=.field)|from_entries' file.json |
  mlr --ijson --opprint cut -xf @ptr
```

That `jq` command, broken down and commented:

```
jq -c '
  .results[] | # iterate over the elements of the .results array 
               # (which are also arrays)

  map(.key=.field) | # for each of those arrays, transform the
                     # elements (which are objects) by adding a 
                     # field of key "key" with same value as that
                     # with "field" key in each, as that's what
                     # from_entries needs

  from_entries | # transforms those [{"key":"foo","value":"bar"}]
                 # (the "field" field is ignored) to {"foo":"bar"}

  del(."@ptr") # deletes the field with key "@ptr" from those
               # objects' file.json
```

The result is not JSON, but several JSONs concatenated together, but both `jq` and `mlr` support that. With `-c` (compact), that's NDJSON (newline-delimited JSON) where we have one JSON per line, also supported by `vd`. To get proper JSON, we'd need:

```
jq -c '.results|map(map(.key=.field)|from_entries|del(."@ptr"))' file.json
```

Where we use `map` on the `.results` array so it results in another JSON array instead of iterating over the elements. So the end result is one large arrays. That's also supported by `jq` (obviously as that's proper JSON), `mlr` and `vd`, is a bit longer to type and means those tools need to read up to the closing `]` at the very end before they have anything to chew on. In practice, I've not checked whether that made any difference in terms of performance though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Miller! I'll try it next. I currently use `jtbl -m` ([jtbl](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jtbl)) for my tabulation.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another:

```
$ jq -r '.results|map(map({key:.field,value}|select(.key!="@ptr"))|from_entries)|(.[0]|keys_unsorted) as $keys|([$keys]+map([.[$keys[]]]))[]|@csv' input.json | xsv table
@timestamp               CpuReserved  CpuUtilized        MemoryReserved  MemoryUtilized
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000  8192.0       4056.412942708333  61440           4311
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000  8192.0       4056.412942708333  61440           4311
```

Notes:

- `from_entries` will convert an array of key-value pairs to an object.
- To convert array-of-objects to csv: [View Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq).
- `xsv table` is for pretty-printing only, you can remove it.

Comment: I like this answer most since it uses jq only (no mlr) and works without explicit indices.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer:

```
jq -r '([ "@timestamp", "CpuReserved", "CpuUtilized", "MemoryReserved", "MemoryUtilized"] | (., map(length*"-"))), ( .results[] | [.[0,1,2,3,4].value] ) | @tsv' |column -ts $'\t'
@timestamp               CpuReserved  CpuUtilized         MemoryReserved  MemoryUtilized
----------               -----------  -----------         --------------  --------------
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000  8192.0       4056.412942708333   61440           4311
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000  8192.0       4056.412942708333   61440           4311
2023-07-03 08:27:00.000  8192.0       1056.0744270833331  61440           4436
2023-07-03 08:27:00.000  8192.0       1056.0744270833331  61440           4436
2023-07-03 08:26:00.000  8192.0       2756.6764583333334  61440           5138
2023-07-03 08:26:00.000  8192.0       2756.6764583333334  61440           5138
2023-07-03 08:25:00.000  8192.0       5715.494895833333   61440           6600
2023-07-03 08:25:00.000  8192.0       5715.494895833333   61440           6600
2023-07-03 08:24:00.000  8192.0       7977.704166666666   61440           8451
2023-07-03 08:24:00.000  8192.0       7977.704166666666   61440           8451
2023-07-03 08:23:00.000  8192.0       7288.051666666666   61440           4757
2023-07-03 08:23:00.000  8192.0       7288.051666666666   61440           4757
2023-07-03 08:22:00.000  8192.0       4286.02375          61440           4815
2023-07-03 08:22:00.000  8192.0       4286.02375          61440           4815
2023-07-03 08:21:00.000  8192.0       3357.523776041666   61440           2146
2023-07-03 08:21:00.000  8192.0       3357.523776041666   61440           2146
2023-07-03 08:20:00.000  8192.0       990.2647916666666   61440           1692
2023-07-03 08:20:00.000  8192.0       990.2647916666666   61440           1692
2023-07-03 08:19:00.000  8192.0       4533.409375         61440           1816
2023-07-03 08:19:00.000  8192.0       4533.409375         61440           1816
2023-07-03 08:18:00.000  8192.0       939.4855208333333   61440           1810
2023-07-03 08:18:00.000  8192.0       939.4855208333333   61440           1810
2023-07-03 08:17:00.000  8192.0       4770.659791666667   61440           1924
2023-07-03 08:17:00.000  8192.0       4770.659791666667   61440           1924
2023-07-03 08:16:00.000  8192.0       410.5300065104166   61440           1417
2023-07-03 08:16:00.000  8192.0       410.5300065104166   61440           1417
2023-07-03 08:15:00.000  8192.0       702.310791015625    61440           792
2023-07-03 08:15:00.000  8192.0       702.310791015625    61440           792
2023-07-03 08:14:00.000  8192.0       0.0                 61440           0
2023-07-03 08:14:00.000  8192.0       0.0                 61440           0
```

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the a solution.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining how it works and why it's better than the earlier answers.

Answer (score 2):

Another take that uses `jq` to emit tab-separated values, and `column` to prettify it

```bash
jq -r '
  .results
  | first as $first
  | [$first | map(.field)] + [.[] | map(.value)]
  | map(.[:-1])[]
  | @tsv
' file.json | column -t -s $'\t'
```

```
@timestamp               CpuReserved  CpuUtilized        MemoryReserved  MemoryUtilized
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000  8192.0       4056.412942708333  61440           4311
2023-07-03 08:28:00.000  8192.0       4056.412942708333  61440           4311
```